# Setting Metadata on azure blob in js

Tags: javascript, azure-blob-storage

I see examples for c#, but I cannot find implement info for js. How do I set metadata for blob in js?

```
const metadata = {name, selection}

await blockBlobClient.upload(file);
await blockBlobClient.setMetadata(container, file, metadata)
```

I am looking at this link and it calls `setMetadata` but it doesn't set:

http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#setBlobMetadata__anchor

Comment: What's the SDK you're using? I have a feeling that you are mixing 2 different SDKs.

Comment: Im using `@azure/storage-blob@12.1.1`. What is the other one?

Comment: `azure-storage` - This is the older SDK which is now deprecated. You're using `setMetadata` from the old SDK. Please use this method instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#setMetadata_Metadata__BlobSetMetadataOptions_.

Comment: @GauravMantri ahh thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [@gaurav mantri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri) for your suggestion..

Converting your suggestion as answer to help reach other community members.

**solution** by @gaurav mantri:

To  set metadata for blob in js ,you may use

`setMetadata(metadata?: Metadata, options?: BlobSetMetadataOptions)`  when using new azure-storage SDK  (azure sdk for java script) as the old azure-storage SDK  is deprecated .

Please Refer these for the same :

[BlockBlobClient class | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#setMetadata_Metadata__BlobSetMetadataOptions_)

[BlobSetMetadataOptions interface | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blobsetmetadataoptions?view=azure-node-latest#abortSignal)

Comment: Please don't do this. You shouldn't take other peoples' comments and convert them to your own answer. The person commenting could have created their own answer, if deemed necessary. Also, this question doesn't really need an answer - it was a one-time issue caused by using an older SDK, and should be closed at this point (as typo/not reproducible).